# Sharepoint search folder names and file names

Tags: file, search, sharepoint, directory

Setting up share point searching is quite daunting.

I would like to make it so that a user can put an search term in the search box and if that term exists in the folder or file name anywhere on the share point site it will return that folder or file.

Is that possible? If so, how do I set it up.

This is share point version 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how SharePoint Search works out of the box. If that's not the behavior you are seeing than it might have been broken while you were trying to configure it. If that's the case, deleting the entire Search Service and starting from scratch could be the safest and the fastest way...